# Python [Nested Dictionary] - How to add new key/values to create this structure of dictionary: d = {key:{key:value, key:value, key:value}}

Tags: python, dictionary

I hope you're good.
Can you help me to create this structure of dictionary and add the values in a loop?

```
d = {'key1':{'key(a)':'value', 'key(b)':'value', 'key(c)':'value'}, 'key2':{'key(a)':'value', 'key(b)':'value', 'key(c)':'value'}}
```

Below, a real example for you to understand my goal

```
d = {'ABCD3':{'2010':'25.0', '2011':'28.0', '2012':'24.0'}, RBRP11{'2010':'21.0', '2011':'30.0', '2012':'40.0'}}
```

This kind of structure will be easy to search after or do you have a better suggestion of structure?

Comment: something like this: `d['key'] = {}`

Comment: Yes, but without overwriting the previous one. I'm having trouble to make it possible. I tried like this: d[key] = {key:values}
where key is a string. But for some reason the dictionary never update right.

Comment: if the value of the key is a dictionary You could do: `d['key']['new_key'] = value`

Comment: use `defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: @Matiiss, I'm getting an error

Comment: @LuizHenriqueSáSantos that tells nothing, what error are You getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaultdict is what you need:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
```

then you can do:

```
d['foo'][a] = 1
d['foo'].update({'b': 2, 'c': 3})
```

if you want to nest deeper:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
d['foo']['bar'] = dict(a=1)
d['foo']['bar']['b'] = 2
d['foo']['bar'].update({'c': 3})
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a loooot!!!!!!!!!!! 
One doubt, how do I access this kind of dictionary?? Is it like the others?

Comment: same as a regular dict

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The best for you. I was dying with it ...